# How to use Intrinsic Functions in Python AWS CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use Amazon's Intrinsic Functions from their CloudFormation in the Python CDK but I am struggling to get it to work.

I'm creating a Lambda in CDK and adding a policy statement. In this policy statement I give the Lambda access to S3 actions to an S3 bucket **that is also created in the CDK above it.** I want to give this lambda permissions *only* to the S3 bucket resource (as opposed to using `resources="*"` or something). I realised I'd need the ARN of the bucket before it had been created - so I asked a colleague who said to use Intrinsic Functions (he does CloudFormation but hasn't used the CDK).

This is where I'm getting stuck - I can't figure out how to use the Intrinsic Functions in order to get the bucket ARN and put that into the resource of the Policy Statement.

Here's my code:

```py
bucket_arn = core.Fn.get_att("BucketIDHere", "Arn")

event_lambda.add_to_role_policy(
    aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions=[
            "s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ListBucket", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "kms:*"
        ],
        resources=[
            bucket_arn
        ]))
```

But I'm getting

```js
raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected Scalar, got {"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/core.Intrinsic@10012"}
```

When I try `cdk diff`. I understand that I'm not getting the ARN correctly, but I don't know how to get it. I've read the docs and know that I probably have to use `IResolveable` and `IResolveContext` but every attempt I've made to use them has failed.

If someone has an example or some solution that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use high-level constructs as much as possible. 
If you have created a bucket in the same stack, you can get the ARN of the bucket by using `bucket_arn` attribute.

```
my_bucket = _s3.Bucket(self, "my_bucket")
arn = my_bucket.bucket_arn
```

You can also import the bucket as a resource if it is not part of your stack.

```
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as _s3
...
 def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
     bucket = _s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(self, "an-identifier", "my-bucket-name")

     event_lambda.add_to_role_policy(
         aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
            ...
            resources=[ bucket.bucket_arn ]
         )
```

Comment: But I thought the whole point of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/Fn.html#aws_cdk.core.Fn.get_att) was that it can resolve the ARN of another resource in the template (i.e not created yet)

Comment: I understand your point. Have you tried using bucket_arn attribute? I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ohhh right! I'll give that a go now and update with the results.

Edit: It worked! Thanks so much. I didn't realise that the bucket I create earlier in the stack has that property! That's really good to know.